# Android ListView not showing while parsing data from JSON server

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview

So i am testing on an android app which implemented on a listview. The list used data fetched from JSON server. The three fields used in the view are IMAGE, NAME, DESCRIPTION. I have tested all the inputs, the data is coming from the server properly, set in the adapter (Checked using LOG tags), but the app is not showing any view, and sometimes crashing. Over in all i am not able to see any listView. Please help... :)

These are the files that my project uses...

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.aditya.jtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    ActorsAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();

        new        ActorsAsynTask().execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/ `jsonActors");
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class ActorsAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                //Log.d("MyFilter2", "" + status + "  Value Recieved: " + params[0]);

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    //Log.d("MyFilter", data);

                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("actors");
                    //Log.d("MyFilterjObj: ", jObj.toString());
                    //Log.d("MyFilterjArray: ", jArray.toString() + "\n" + jArray.length());

                    for(int i = 0; i <= jArray.length(); i++) {
                        Actors actors = new Actors();
                        JSONObject jRealObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        //Log.d("\nMyFilter JRealObject[" + i + "]: ", jRealObject.toString());

                        actors.setName(jRealObject.getString("name"));
                        actors.setDescription(jRealObject.getString("description"));
                        actors.setImage(jRealObject.getString("image"));

                        Log.d("\nMyFilter ["+ i +"]", jRealObject.getString("name"));
                        Log.d("MyFilter ["+ i +"]", jRealObject.getString("description"));
                        Log.d("MyFilter ["+ i +"]", jRealObject.getString("image"));

                        actorsList.add(actors);
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            dialog.cancel();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            if(aBoolean == false){
                //Show a message that data was not parsed
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Actors Adapter

```
package com.example.aditya.jtest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class ActorsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Actors> {

ArrayList<Actors> ArrayListActors;
int Resource;
Context context;
LayoutInflater vi;
ViewHolder holder;


public ActorsAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Actors> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.row, objects);

    ArrayListActors = objects;
    Resource = resource;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = convertView;
    if(v == null){
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    new DownloadImageTask(holder.image).execute(ArrayListActors.get(position).getImage());
    holder.name.setText(ArrayListActors.get(position).getName());
    holder.description .setText(ArrayListActors.get(position).getDescription());

    return v;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    public ImageView image;
    public TextView name;
    public TextView description;
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        String urlDisplay = params[0];
        Bitmap mIcon1 = null;
        try{
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urlDisplay).openStream();
            mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

}

Actors.java

```
package com.example.aditya.jtest;

public class Actors {

private String image;
private String name;
private String description;

public Actors() {
}

public Actors(String name, String description, String image) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.image = image;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

}

Comment: learn how to fetch data from server and set over listview [here](http://androhub.com/android-json-parser/).

Comment: is your url working?

Comment: Yep.. The URL is working...!!

Answer (score 0):

Add in `onPostExecute()` of ActorsAsynTask.

```
adapter = new ActorsAdapter(MainActivity.this, /*Your resource file id*/,actorsList);
list.setAdapter(adapter)
```

That would do.

Comment: Nopes... not working... Application crashing instead.. One question - Does layout has to do anything with it.... ??

Comment: I dont think so.. You just need to initialize the adapter and set it to the list view in onPostExecute(). Otherwise it would be executed before the background process is completed and you may have null list view or partially inflated list view.

Comment: Nah!!.... again not working. I added the above two lines in the "else" block of the onPostExecute(). App is still crashing... :(

Comment: Do it outside else. and tell me whats the logcat says about the error.

Comment: Shifted the code outside else...and here is the log error......Process: com.example.aditya.jtest, PID: 4703
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.aditya.jtest.MainActivity$ActorsAsynTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:110)
            at com.example.aditya.jtest.MainActivity$ActorsAsynTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:44)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)

Comment: at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)

Comment: Okay.. Click on MainActivity.‌​java:110 in logcat. Does that redirect you to the line adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: If yes.. Make sure you add those two lines before adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() .

Comment: Yes... and MainActivity.‌​java:44 points at ActorsAsyncTask.... Still not working.... and after moving the two lines above adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), still the app is crashing ...BUt this time, the logcat is showing error related to LayoutInflator in the ActorsAdapter..... I can't get it, everything is in place, the program should be up and running by now, still this error...

Comment: while initializing your layout inflator.. Change Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE to Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PrivateJobList extends Fragment {

    /**Declaring the data members **/
    List<PrivateData> list;

    PrivateJobListAdapter adapter;

    ListView listview;

    PrivateJobList(){

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.private_job_list,container,false);

         listview=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);
         /*converting or say initializing list as arraylist*/
         list=new ArrayList<PrivateData>();

         /*instantiating the class which deals with fetching*/
     ExecuteTaskprivate executetask= new ExecuteTaskprivate();


         /*calling execute method on class instance*/
         executetask.execute();

         /*initializing the adapter*/
         adapter = new PrivateJobListAdapter(getActivity(),list);

        return v;
    }


/*class to handle background task*/
class ExecuteTaskprivate extends AsyncTask<String, Void,String>{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        /**storing returned value from this method in res variable
         * and pass it to the postData method**/
        String res=postData(params);

        return res;
    }


    /**This method Deals with the posting the client request
     * and storing the response in String variable which is 
     * nothing but a HttpResponse from the server**/
    private String postData(String[] params) {

        String s="";

        try  
        {  
        HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/loginpage/private_jobs_fetching.php");  

        HttpResponse res=  httpClient.execute(httpPost);  

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        HttpEntity httpEntity=res.getEntity();  
        s= readResponse(res);  

        }  
        catch(Exception exception)  {}  
        return s;  
    }
/**this method returns String representation of response from server**/
private String readResponse(HttpResponse res) {
    String return_text="";

    InputStream is = null;
    try{
     is=res.getEntity().getContent();  
     BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);  
     String line="";  
     StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();  
     while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)  
     {  
     sb.append(line);  
     }  


   return_text=sb.toString();
 } catch (Exception e)  
 {  
      e.printStackTrace(); 
 }  
 return return_text;  
}

/**In onPostExecute String variable returned from doInBackground is used as parameter**/
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if(result.length()!=0){

    try {

        /**parsing JSONArray first**/
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        /**looping through it's length**/
        for (int i = 0; i<jArray.length();i++) 
        {
            /**And converting it to the JSONObject**/
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            /**Creating instance of Bean class**/
            PrivateData user= new PrivateData();
            /**fetching data directly from server by providing column names
             * and setting to their respective setter method's of bean class**/
            user.setCompany_name(json_data.getString("company_name"));
            user.setJob_title(json_data.getString("job_title"));
            user.setLocation(json_data.getString("location"));
            user.setEmail(json_data.getString("email"));
            user.setUid(json_data.getInt("uid"));
            /**Adding PrivateData object to the list**/
            list.add(user);
        }
         /**setting the adapter on listview**/
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());  
    }

    }
    else{

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

}

}
```

/***************************************************************************/

```
/**Bean class with data members & their respective setter & getters**/
public class PrivateData {

    String company_name;

    String job_title;

    String location;

    String email;

    int uid;


    public String getCompany_name() {
        return company_name;
    }

    public void setCompany_name(String company_name) {
        this.company_name = company_name;
    }

    public String getJob_title() {
        return job_title;
    }

    public void setJob_title(String job_title) {
        this.job_title = job_title;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(int uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }




}
```

/******************************************************************************/

```
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
/**ListAdapter class**/
public class PrivateJobListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PrivateData> {
    /**data members**/
    Context c;

    //int layout;

    List<PrivateData> list;



    /**Constructor**/
    public PrivateJobListAdapter(Context context,List<PrivateData> objects) {
        super(context,R.layout.row_view, objects);

        this.c=context;
        this.list=objects;

    }


/**this method is used to display your fetched data from server **/
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         View row = convertView;
         /**initializing class which has all textview required for showing column data
          * of table on server**/
         UserHolder holder = null;

         if(row==null){
             /**this is important step if your main class is an Activity
              * then write it as 
              * LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
              * and import android.app.activity**/
             LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(c);
             /****/
             row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_view, parent, false);
               holder = new UserHolder();

               holder.textcompanyname=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textview_company_name);

               holder.textjobtitle=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textview_job_title);

               holder.textlocation=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textview_location);

               holder.textemail=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textview_email);


               /**setting tag**/
               row.setTag(holder);

         }
         else {
             /**getting tag**/
               holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
              }


        return row;
    }

    static class UserHolder {
          TextView textcompanyname;
          TextView textjobtitle;
          TextView textlocation;
          TextView textemail;


         }
}
```

/****************************************************/

```
//private_job_list.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView android:id="@+id/textview_private_job_list"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_rounded"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:text="@string/private_job_list_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>


 <ListView 

     android:id="@+id/list"

     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"></ListView>



</LinearLayout>
```

/*****************************************/

```
//row-view.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_company_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/company_name"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_job_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview_company_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/job_title"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_more"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_rounded"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="@string/btn_more"
        android:textColor="#0099CC" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview_job_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/location"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview_location"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/email"
        android:textSize="18sp" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

/*******************************************/

```
//button_rounded.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#ec0b47"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="30dp"/>    

</shape>
```

/***********************************/

```
//php code


<?php

$host='localhost:3306';
$uname='root';
$pwd='';
$db="mydb";

$connection=mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pwd,$db);
$database=mysqli_select_db($connection,$db);

$query1=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT  * FROM  private_jobs");


while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1))
{

    $result[]=$row;
}

print(json_encode($result));

mysqli_close($connection);

?>



happy coding!!!!
```